# C# Score Counter {Unity3D}

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to make a score counter for my game.
It partly works, whenever the cube reaches (x)11 the score goes up, and the block will be reset to it's beginning position at (x)12.
The problem is, is that whenever the cube reaches (x)11 it will keep counting +1 until (x)12, when it gets reset the score is around 36 most of the time.
It keeps doing this and I have no clue what I have done wrong, full on noobie here.
Here is my code:

```
void Start () {
    beginPositie = new Vector3 (-4, 0, 0);
    transform.position = beginPositie;
    score = 0;
}


void Update () {
    snelheid = Random.Range (2, 5);
    transform.Translate (snelheid * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    if(gameObject.transform.position.x>= 12){
        transform.position = beginPositie;
    }

}

void OnGUI() {
    if (gameObject.transform.position.x == 11) {
        score = score + 1;
    }
    GUI.skin = textSkin;
    GUI.Label (new Rect (10, 10, 300, 100), "Score: " + score);

}
```

Comment: 'snelheid' means 'speed'
'beginPositie' means 'startingPosition'

Comment: It should stop counting when it reaches 11 and should never count again until what happens?

Comment: Try to use English variable names when posting questions in English StackOverflow. Also, as an expat working in NL, I'll thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is causing the problem:

```
if (gameObject.transform.position.x == 11)
```

Do not compare floats with `=` because it is never guaranteed that the value of `gameObject.transform.position.x` will exactly be `11`.

That should b changed to:

```
if (gameObject.transform.position.x >= 11)
```

Another unrelated problem is `OnGUI()`. Don't use it. Use the new [Unity UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui).

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, I found another way. Instead of creating the +1/++ script part in the void OnGUI, I replaced the bit to void Update as last line using 'score++;'. This completely solved the problem. Eventhough I solved my problem my own way I also learned that I can't compare floats with = :)

Comment: Good. So, you remove `OnGUI()`?

Comment: No, I did not remove `OnGUI()`
I got rid of `if (gameObject.transform.position.x == 11) {
        score = score + 1;
    }`
To `update` and not as the massive code but as `score++;`
In the void `OnGui` still is the code `GUI.skin = textSkin;
    GUI.Label (new Rect (10, 10, 300, 100), "Score: " + score);` Since this will show my score counter.

Comment: Ok. I do recommend you do remove it. I am not forcing you but you should be using the new Unity UI system. Take a look at the link I posted. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: you can store in a boolean if you have increased the score this cycle and reset it on reseting the cube position:

```
bool countedThisCycle; // What you use to determine if you have scored this cycle.
void Start () {
    beginPositie = new Vector3 (-4, 0, 0);
    transform.position = beginPositie;
    score = 0;
    countedThisCycle = false; // Make sure you count the first one.
}


void Update () {
    snelheid = Random.Range (2, 5);
    transform.Translate (snelheid * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    if(gameObject.transform.position.x>= 12){
        transform.position = beginPositie;
        countedThisCycle = false; // Make sure you can count the next one.
    }
}

void OnGUI() {
    if (gameObject.transform.position.x == 11 && !countedThisCycle) { // Check that you haven't counted this one.
        score = score + 1;
        countedThisCycle = true; // Make sure you don't count it again.
    }
    GUI.skin = textSkin;
    GUI.Label (new Rect (10, 10, 300, 100), "Score: " + score);
}
```

Your other option which programatically is more correct, is to count when you do the reset, but that probably beats the purpose of counting when you reach 11.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you already fixed your problem I think I can help you understand what went wrong.

We dont know how often `update()` and `OnGUI()` are called. It is very plausable that `OnGUI()` is called more often then `Update()`. Which would make the call stack look something like this:

```
Update();
OnGUI();
OnGUI();
OnGUI();
OnGUI();
OnGUI();
Update();
OnGUI();
OnGUI();
OnGUI();
OnGUI();
OnGUI();
```

Now if your `Update()` recalculates and evaluates position to 11, your `OnGUI` will see 11 and update your score. Since `OnGUI` is called more often it will keep seeing that 11. 5 times in my example, resulting in your score being raised 5 times in a row, before the next `Update()` happens.

My advice would be to keep everything game logic related to game logic methods and everything UI related in UI related methods. Avoid mixing them!

Comment: This is a great tip and it made me understand more of C#!
I will try to avoid mixing them from now on, but since I am a total rookie at C# it will most probably still happen every now and then.
Thanks a lot still! :)